# Cypress: check if an element is present based on one of its attributes

Tags: jquery, cypress

I'm writing Cypress End-to-End tests where I need first to check if a specific button is present on my web page (conditionnal testing).

This is what I did:

```js
  cy.get('body')
    .then($body => {

      if ($body.has(".myClass").length) {
        //DO SOMETHING
      }
    })
```

This works fine, but when I try to select the subelement based on its attribute instead of a class, then the subelement is not found. Meaning this didn't work:

```js
  cy.get('body')
    .then($body => {

      if ($body.has("div[data-cy='deleteButton']").length) {
        //DO SOMETHING
      }
    })
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Anyone a clue?

I experimented further, and it looks that even when using class, some subelements can not found. Below you see the HTML structure and the class i could use as identifier, the class I couldn't use as identifier and the data-cy attribute I'm trying to work with:
[image]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? I can see in your code posted here `data-cy='deleteButton'` but in your html image it is `data-cy='deleteTestlaufButton'`

Comment: In the question I just first simplified the value for readibility, the screenshot come from my production code, hence the difference

Answer (score 4):

That looks like the problem with conditional testing and **asynchronous loading**. The `if` statement might be running before the page has loaded.

If you take a simplified and static version of the page

```html
<body>
  <div data-cy="deleteButton"></div>
</body>
```

and open it in the browser, the test passes

```js
cy.get('body').then($body => {
  const exists = $body.has("div[data-cy='deleteButton']").length
  expect(exists).to.eq(true)
})
```

so it's likely the problem is due to loading delays.

Instead of `$body`, please try a static element close to that section of the page that also loads asynchronously but is not conditional

I'm guessing

```js
cy.get('div[title="Testlaufverwaltung und Testbericht"]').then($title => {
  const exists = $title.has("div[data-cy='deleteButton']").length
  expect(exists).to.eq(true)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($body.find("div[data-cy='deleteButton']").length) {
        //DO SOMETHING
      }
```

Comment: I had already tried with find, but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: Can you post your HTML by editing the original post?

Comment: Sure, thanks for having alook on it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.attr` jquery method like this:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.attr('data-cy') == 'deleteTestlaufButton') {
    //DO SOMETHING
  }
})
```